# Different event handlers for different apps?

Tags: safari, mail.app, email, web-browser

Is it possible to have different applications open links in different browsers?

For example, I would like to have all links in Thunderbird open in Firefox, while links in Mail should open in Safari.

*Ideally*, I would like to have different *accounts* in Thunderbird open in different browsers (work in Opera, home in Chrome, etc).

How can part A be done, if it can be? And is part B possible?

Comment: I'd love to be proven wrong, but I don't think that can be done...

Comment: @Tetsujin - I'm with you: I haven't figured a way to do it yet, and doubt it's possible :|

Comment: Yes, in principle I suspect this can be done. You would need to modify an existing browser app with customized event handling that you would then send all the links to. This custom browser would have to be able to query the OS for enough info on the foreground or sending app to infer which other browser to delegate the link to. Tho I haven't done it, or seen it done.